# Ordering MySQL table using timestamp from different table

Tags: mysql, timestamp, inner-join

I have two tables, `group` and `groupAccess`. One contains information for each "group", and the other contains all the times a group is accessed, including it's unique ID and timestamp.

My goal is to order all groups by the most recent time they were accessed.

I've got half way there, this query allows me to get all the groups in the correct order, however there are duplicate groups that I need to remove.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM groups a
INNER JOIN groupAccess b ON a.group_id = b.group_access_id
ORDER BY access_time DESC
```

I've tried using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`, however this breaks the (currently) correct order of the groups. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max()` and `GROUP BY` to find the latest access time of each group, and then join that table with `group`.  That is:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , b.last_access_time
FROM 
    groups a
    INNER JOIN (
        select
            group_access_id
            , max(access_time) as last_access_time
        from groupAccess 
        group by 
            group_access_id
    ) b ON a.group_id = b.group_access_id
ORDER BY b.last_access_time DESC
```